# ViewContext.ParentActionViewContext is null when trying to access parent ContentArea in EPiServer

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, episerver, episerver-8

I'm trying to use the approach [shown here](http://world.episerver.com/blogs/Per-Magne-Skuseth/Dates/2013/8/Letting-your-blocks-know-where-they-are/) to allow my blocks in EPiServer to query their index within a parent ContentArea. I already do this in another project (project A) and am now trying to do it again in a new project (project B). But for some reason in the new project, the `ViewContext.ParentActionViewContext` is null. I started comparing the differences between the two and I notice in Project A, `IsChildAction` is true and the `RouteData.DataTokens` contains only one key = 'ParentActionDataContext', but in Project B, `IsChildAction` is false and The `RouteData.DataTokens` contains all the keys for the main request. Ok, so given that the description of the `ParentActionViewContext` property is:

> An object that contains the view context information for the parent action method.

It makes sense that it would be null in Project B if there is no child action. The problem is, I don't know why Project A executes rendering the ContentArea as a child action but Project B does not. Comparing the call stacks, I can see that it branches off in the two different directions within the EPiServer assembly (top 2 frames of each stack below):

**Project A**

```
EPiServer.dll!EPiServer.Web.Mvc.PartialRequest.RenderAction(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper helper, string action, string controller, object routeValues) Unknown
EPiServer.dll!EPiServer.Web.Mvc.MvcContentRenderer.Render(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper helper, EPiServer.Web.Mvc.PartialRequest partialRequestHandler, EPiServer.Core.IContentData contentData, EPiServer.DataAbstraction.TemplateModel templateModel) Unknown
EPiServer.dll!EPiServer.Web.Mvc.Html.IContentDataExtensions.RenderContentData(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper html, EPiServer.Core.IContentData contentData, bool isContentInContentArea, EPiServer.DataAbstraction.TemplateModel templateModel, EPiServer.Web.Mvc.IContentRenderer contentRenderer)  Unknown
EPiServer.dll!EPiServer.Web.Mvc.Html.ContentAreaRenderer.RenderContentAreaItem(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper htmlHelper, EPiServer.Core.ContentAreaItem contentAreaItem, string templateTag, string htmlTag, string cssClass)   Unknown
EPiServer.dll!EPiServer.Web.Mvc.Html.ContentAreaRenderer.RenderContentAreaItems(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper htmlHelper, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<EPiServer.Core.ContentAreaItem> contentAreaItems)  Unknown
EPiServer.dll!EPiServer.Web.Mvc.Html.ContentAreaRenderer.Render(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper htmlHelper, EPiServer.Core.ContentArea contentArea)   Unknown
EPiServer.dll!EPiServer.Web.Mvc.Html.ContentAreaExtensions.RenderContentArea(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper htmlHelper, EPiServer.Core.ContentArea contentArea)  Unknown
App_Web_zaun2obg.dll!ASP.util_views_shared_displaytemplates_contentarea_ascx.__Render__control1(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter __w, System.Web.UI.Control parameterContainer) Line 4  C#
```

**Project B**

```
EPiServer.dll!EPiServer.Web.Mvc.MvcContentRenderer.HandleRenderTemplateWithViewEngine(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper helper, EPiServer.Core.IContentData contentData, EPiServer.DataAbstraction.TemplateModel templateModel) Unknown
EPiServer.dll!EPiServer.Web.Mvc.MvcContentRenderer.Render(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper helper, EPiServer.Web.Mvc.PartialRequest partialRequestHandler, EPiServer.Core.IContentData contentData, EPiServer.DataAbstraction.TemplateModel templateModel) Unknown
EPiServer.dll!EPiServer.Web.Mvc.Html.IContentDataExtensions.RenderContentData(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper html, EPiServer.Core.IContentData contentData, bool isContentInContentArea, EPiServer.DataAbstraction.TemplateModel templateModel, EPiServer.Web.Mvc.IContentRenderer contentRenderer)  Unknown
EPiServer.dll!EPiServer.Web.Mvc.Html.ContentAreaRenderer.RenderContentAreaItem(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper htmlHelper, EPiServer.Core.ContentAreaItem contentAreaItem, string templateTag, string htmlTag, string cssClass)   Unknown
EPiServer.dll!EPiServer.Web.Mvc.Html.ContentAreaRenderer.RenderContentAreaItems(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper htmlHelper, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<EPiServer.Core.ContentAreaItem> contentAreaItems)  Unknown
EPiServer.dll!EPiServer.Web.Mvc.Html.ContentAreaRenderer.Render(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper htmlHelper, EPiServer.Core.ContentArea contentArea)   Unknown
EPiServer.dll!EPiServer.Web.Mvc.Html.ContentAreaExtensions.RenderContentArea(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper htmlHelper, EPiServer.Core.ContentArea contentArea)  Unknown
App_Web_myevwxkt.dll!ASP.util_views_shared_displaytemplates_contentarea_ascx.__Render__control1(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter __w, System.Web.UI.Control parameterContainer) Line 4  C#
```

But I call both the same way:

**Project A:**

```
@Html.PropertyFor(m => m.CurrentPage.WallBlocks)
```

**Project B:**

```
@Html.PropertyFor(m => m.CurrentPage.DepartmentalSupportBlocks)
```

Any idea what's going on or how I can make it work so I can get at the parent ContentArea in my Html helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I was correct in thinking that the `ParentActionViewContext` was null because the block was not being executed as a child view. The reason seems to be because my block did not have a controller. It looks like EPiServer will render Blocks that have a controller as child Actions, but those that do not have a controller as part of the same request. I guess this is the reason why it's recommended to not use a controller for your Blocks for efficiency reasons. However, if you need information about the parent `ContentArea`, it seems you do need to have a controller.

P.S. Make sure you return PartialView(...) not View(...) from your block controller so you don't spend an extra couple hours trying to figure out why it's yelling at you saying,

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'Castle.Proxies.[MyBlock]Proxy', but this dictionary requires a model
>   item of type '[My default layout's model type]'

Comment: To get more info what's going under the hood: you can read more here - http://blog.tech-fellow.net/2015/05/30/content-area-under-the-hood-part-2/#whathappensaftertemplateisselected